# How can I revive dried out fudge?

Tags: fudge

Someone gave me a couple pounds of fudge (chocolate and peanut butter) in approximately 1/2" slices. I let it sit in a paper bag for a couple weeks and now it's all dried out and hard. 
**Is there a way to revive this and make it like new again without ruining it even more?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to save your fudge, you need to rehydrate it.

One way to do so is to place the fudge in an airtight container with some source of moisture and leave it to absorb overnight. This could be:

- A bowl of water
- A damp paper towel
- A slice of non-stale bread

You could also gently heat the fudge with some moisture. This could be done:

- In the microwave - microwave in short increments with a glass of (warm) water, which creates steam for the fudge to absorb, until the fudge no longer feels/looks dried out
- In the oven - wrap the fudge in foil with a tiny bit of water, perhaps 2-3 teaspoons and bake at a low temperature (120-140C or 248-284F) for 10-20 minutes, or until the fudge no longer feels/looks dried out

Comment: The old "damp paper towel in a ZipLock bag" trick worked for me. Thanks for the answer, @mestackoverflow